# Structure data in Firebase Firestore

Tags: database, mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need help understanding the best approach to structure my firestore data.

I come from traditional SQL background and have a little bit of nosql mongodb background as well. I am building a small football prediction app and here is the user flow:

User:

1. User registers/signs in
2. They can pick a contest to join
3. Enter their predictions every week

Admin:

1. Create contests and add/edit games to contest every week (an api will fetch all the data like fixtures and results)
2. Set a deadline for when users can enter their last prediction for the game week

Other:

1. Leaderboard

Now I did create a diagram on how I would traditionally structure this data but it would be nice if someone can exaplain to me the simplest approach to structuring such an app in Firestore
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks reasonable but I would be concerned about storing the passwords in Firestore DB. Firestore should not ideally be concerned with authentication. Check [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) for different auth options with Firebase. You'll probably end up only having to store the user ID as other information is in the [`User`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User) object.

Also check out [Supported data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). You probably want to change varchar(x) to (UTF-8) string or byte types.  Moreover, there is a reference type so you could reference the actual user document from the other tables.

One main design will be whether to use nested collections ([Hierarchical Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#hierarchical-data)).

You might be able to nest score under competitions.